# mod_proxy_html and AJAX Response

Tags: mod-proxy-html

I am using `mod_proxy_html` and the AJAX response is wrapped inside HTML

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>AJAX RESPONSE</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is done by `mod_proxy_html` and I want to avoid this happening.

Answer (score 0):

In general mod_proxy_html is only supposed to act on responses with Content-Type set to text/html or application/xhtml+xml: maybe you can change your Ajax response's content type?